# Checking age when signing up to website in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently writing a site for reviewing pubs in my local area and want to have age verification on signing up for the site (afterall why would anyone under 18 be interested in going to the pub?)

I have

```
if($_POST[d_of_b] > date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-18 Years"))) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, you\'re not old enough to use this site yet, please come back when you\'re 18.';
}
```

and it sort of works, but `date("Y-m-d, strtotime("-18 Years)` seems to remove 18 years from the end of the previous year, so at time of writing it will show errors unless the date of birth is =< 31/12/1997. Has anyone got a way of doing this which will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DateTime` and diff http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php.

So, you could end up with something like:

```
if ((new DateTime($_POST['d_of_b']))->diff(new DateTime)->y < 18)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
    function validateAge($then, $min)
{
    // $then will first be a string-date
    $then = strtotime($then);
    //The age to be over, over +18
    $min = strtotime('+18 years', $then);
    echo $min;
    if(time() < $min)  {
        die('Not 18'); 
    }
}
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Thanks for taking the time V, I was avoiding making it a function as it's the only place I envision using it on the site, as Ross's code works perfectly I've gone with that for now.